# Why does no warning message appear, when a file opened in binary mode and buffering set to 1 (line buffering)?

Tags: python, io

I was reading the Python implementation of the `io` module, at https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2cb445635e99d4401949cabebd373288cfdd0138/Lib/_pyio.py

In this code snippet below,

```
if binary and buffering == 1:
        import warnings
        warnings.warn("line buffering (buffering=1) isn't supported in binary "
                      "mode, the default buffer size will be used",
                      RuntimeWarning, 2)
```

The code says when a file IO is opened in binary mode, and buffering is set to 1 (`buffering=1`), a warning message appears.

But when I tested it using the following code,

```
file=open(r"D:\After Effects\after_effect project\Python_file handling\FIle_constructor\files\file2.txt", "w+b", buffering=1)
file.write(b"hello\n")
```

No such warning appears. Why does it not respond with the warning as has been given in the source code?

Comment: I'm getting this warning. What is your Python version?

Comment: I am using Python 3.11. Incidentally, I tried using io.open(), and it raises the warning, but not with the builtin open().

Comment: I get the warning with Python 3.10.2 on win32.