# Can you help me understand the __init__() constructor of the io.FileIO(RawIOBase) class?

Tags: python, io

This is an extension of my previous post at [Why does no warning message appear, when a file opened in binary mode and buffering set to 1 (line buffering)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76372772/why-does-no-warning-message-appear-when-a-file-opened-in-binary-mode-and-buffer).

I have been trying to read and understand the inner workings of the `io.open()`, at https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2cb445635e99d4401949cabebd373288cfdd0138/Lib/_pyio.py#L607.

I see that `FileIO` inherits the `io.RawIOBase` base class. Within the `io.FileIO(RawIOBase)`, a class variable has been declared `_fd=-1`. And within the constructor, there is a conditional

```
class FileIO(RawIOBase):
    _fd = -1
    _created = False
    _readable = False
    _writable = False
    _appending = False
    _seekable = None
    _closefd = True

def __init__(self, file, mode='r', closefd=True, opener=None): 
            if self._fd >= 0:
            # Have to close the existing file first.
            try:
                if self._closefd:
                    os.close(self._fd)
            finally:
                self._fd = -1
```

I don't know if I am missing some information! Here, within the constructor, `file` is what is returned by the `os.fspath`, which is either a `string` or `bytes`, but not an `integer`. Then how did they use the `if self._fd >= 0:` within the `__init__()`, constructor.

Also, it says that "

```
"""The file will be created if it
        doesn't exist when opened for writing or appending; it will be truncated
        when opened for writing.  A FileExistsError will be raised if it already
        exists when opened for creating"""
```

But when I tried to create an unbuffered binary stream using `io.FileIO`, by passing a file that already exists, it didn't raise the said `FileExistsError`

Comment: Here, I don't see an explicit assignment of file descriptor to the class variable "_fd"

Comment: If you look further into the implementation you will see that *file* can be *int*

Comment: Actually, I could not find it. Could you help locate it?

Comment: I recommend learning some Python language basics before heading to ChatGPT for solutions

Comment: Actually, I am a beginner, and learning OOP myself. I just wanted to check, within the __init__ constructor, where the file descriptor of the file, passed into the FileIO class, is defined.